# Join two tables and create a new one in SQL

Tags: ms-access

I am new to SQL and trying to apply a concept of Joins in MS-access.

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2:

I want a query which will create a Table 3:

Ideally i want all the data from both tables but wherever the ID's are matching in both tables, the category should become '3'

Can someone please help me with this query. Thanks in advance.[image][image]

I have attached the samples for your reference

Comment: What DBMS do you use? SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, DB2, SQLite, Firebird, etc ...? And what if some rows match the `ID` but have different values in `Name?

Comment: Will the categories in the source tables necessarily be 1 and 2? What if they are other values? What if one of them is already 3 and there's a match with a different category for the same `ID,Name` in the other table?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to `UNION ALL` the two table entries
- Then take the `SUM(Category)` by `GROUP BY ID, Name`

So the query will be

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Category) AS Category
FROM  (
    SELECT ID, Name, Category FROM Table1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Name, Category FROM Table2
) GROUP BY ID, Name
```

You can insert the entries into the third table.